# Storing a big 2d map in memory efficiently

Tags: javascript

i'm creating a 2d tiled game pokemon-like so i'm creating a map editor to create the maps.
The game will be on the web, so the map editor must be web.
I don't know how to store the map in memory:
I thought i could use a 2 dimensional array, but the map can be bery big, leading to a massive memory usage/out of memory problem.
How can i store the entire map in memory efficiently, without using all the browser memory?

Comment: Just to get an idea of the issue... what are the approximate dimensions of the map in tiles?  Also, how much info is being stored about each tile?  Is it just one number, or is each cell an object with multiple properties?  If it is just one number, one trick is to treat the map array as one big text string, with each character representing a tile.  That's about as efficient as it gets, without using compression or dynamic partial loading.

Comment: @kbelder Each tile has the filename,x/y offset,x/y size in it.

Comment: Ah.  That's different than what I was expecting :)  One suggestion might be to not store the filename for each tile, but instead just store a number... when drawing the map, use that number as an index in an array to lookup the filename of the image.  That would probably eliminate a lot of duplicate entries...   However, it is hard to say without knowing the details of your map.

Answer (score 1):

The standard seems to be not having the entire map loaded in memory, but only the current viewport or `bounds` as it is referred to in the mapping world.

You would check the bounds on any map pan, scroll or zoom and fetch the corresponding tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a map shouldn't be too big in memory. You can make special map files that store the data in json.

```php
echo json_encode(array(array(4, 2, 6, 4), array(4, 2, 6, 4), array(4, 2, 6, 4), array(4, 2, 6, 4)));
```

```
// do some loading of the generated file
var map = <...>, i, j; // loaded data

for(i in map) {
  if(map.hasOwnProperty(map[i]))
  // etc
}
```

The numbers in the array point to an id for example, just to keep it small. You can also put tile names in there instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also making a 2d tiled game...

You could have separate arrays to make it easier for you to create the map, like this:

```
var mapX = [];
var mapY = [];
var mapType = [];
```

mapX is an array for the x positions of the tiles, mapY is an array for the y positions of the tiles, and mapType describes the type of tile (e.g. 0 = water, 1 = grass, 2 = dirt, 3 = rock, etc.). Then you could have a function to make tiles like this:

```
function createTile(x,y,type){
mapX.push(x);
mapY.push(y);
mapType.push(type);
}
```

In use:

```
createTile(50,50,1);
```

would create a grass tile at the position (50,50).